# creating a document set library instance via workflow returns id variable that is -1 from the actual id

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

Steps:

1) using sharepoint 2010 designer workflow, create an instance of a Document Set and have the ID of the created instance returned.

2) set the returned ID to a field in the list that was used to initiate the workflow.

3) look at the id of the value returned, vs the actual id of the document set instance.

**result:**  the returned value is -1 of the actual value.

**expected:** the same id values.

i tried to "get around" this by adding a calculation step to add 1 to the value returned.

what it did was add 1 to the end of the string value returned (so if the wrongid was 322 and i expected 323 to be the final calculated number, it returns 3221).

Comment: can you store the ID in a workflow variable? That way you can set the datatype to integer which will help with your calculation

Comment: i stored the ID in a workflow variable that i setup as an integer. i then perform the calculation, but i can't write the value back to a field without an error in the workflow.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: it is a generic Coersion error in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't an answer, it is a workaround.

use infopath to set the default value of e.g. PALID = TempPALID +1
in the workflow itself, set the list item id to TempPALID

then when i construct my URL to go to the PALID it populates when the form is loaded with the correct value.